# Why my <EditText> fields are empty after coming back to fragment from navigation menu?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a problem with my app, I have an navigation bar which with I switch between fragments, in first fragment i have view for the items that I add in third fragment. I use MVVM and everything works fine I add staff in third fragment and it appears in first one, no problem here, but when I add something and then switch fragment to see changes then switch to add something again  my app sees EditText strings as empty (eventhough they are not in the view of app).

My code for switching between navigation :

```
fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.tag)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    /**Navigation menu */
    val menuNavigationClickListener =
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_products -> {
                    toolbar.title = "Products"
                    openFragment(productsFragment)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.navigation_dishes -> {
                    toolbar.title = "Dishes"
                    openFragment(dishesFragment)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.navigation_add -> {
                    toolbar.title = "Add"
                    openFragment(addFragment)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: posted 3rd fragment

```
class Add : Fragment(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
val NEW_SPINNER_ID = 1
val ANOTHER_SPINNER_ID = 2
var productPosition: Int? = null
var dishPosition: Int? = null

fun showToast(context: FragmentActivity? = activity, message: String, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_LONG) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, duration) .show()
}
/**Spinner implementation TODO */

override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
    showToast(activity,"nothing selected ",3)
}

override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    when (parent?.id) {
        1 -> {productPosition = position
            showToast(message ="product list")
        }
        else -> {dishPosition = position
            showToast(message = "dish list")
        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)




    /** initialize ui with viewmodel*/

    fun initializeUi() {

        // Get the AddViewModelFactory with all of it's dependencies constructed
        val factory = InjectorUtils.provideAddViewModelFactory()
        // Use ViewModelProviders class to create / get already created AddViewModel
        // for this view (activity)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), factory)
            .get(AddViewModel::class.java)

        /** BINDERS FOR BUTTONS AND FIELDS */
        val name     = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_name).text
        val price    = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_price).text
        val tax      = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_tax).text
        val waste    = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_waste).text
        val weightOfAddedProduct = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_weight)
        val addButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.addProduct)
        val createDishButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.new_dish_button)
        val addProductToDishBtn = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.add_product_to_dish)



        /** ADAPTERs FOR SPINNERs */
        var productAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,viewModel.getProducts().value!!.map { it.name })
        productAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        val mySpinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.mySpinner)
        with(mySpinner)
        {
            adapter = productAdapter
            setSelection(0, false)
            onItemSelectedListener = this@Add
            prompt = "Select product"
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
        mySpinner.id = NEW_SPINNER_ID


        var dishesAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,viewModel.getDishes().value!!.map{it.name})
        dishesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        val dishSpinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.dishSpinner)
        with(dishSpinner){
            adapter = dishesAdapter
            setSelection(0,false)
            onItemSelectedListener = this@Add
            prompt = "Select dish"
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
        dishSpinner.id =  ANOTHER_SPINNER_ID


        /**OBSERVING LIVEDATA FROM ADDVIEWMODEL
         *  WHICH OBSERVES LIVEDATA IN REPOSITORY
         *  WHICH OBSERVES LIVEDATA FROM DAO */

        viewModel.getProducts().observe(this, Observer { products ->
            productAdapter.clear()
            products.forEach { product ->
                productAdapter.add(product.name)
            }
        })

        viewModel.getDishes().observe(this, Observer { dishes ->
            dishesAdapter.clear()
            dishes.forEach{dish ->
                dishesAdapter.add(dish.name)
            }

        })

        /** BUTTONS FUNCTIONALITY */

        createDishButton.setOnClickListener{
            CreateDish().show(childFragmentManager,CreateDish.TAG)
        }
        addButton.setOnClickListener{
            if(name.isNullOrEmpty()||
                price.isNullOrEmpty()||
                tax.isNullOrEmpty()||
                waste.isNullOrEmpty()){showToast(message = "Fill all data!")}
            else {
                val product = Product(
                    name.toString(),
                    price.toString().toDouble(),
                    tax.toString().toDouble(),
                    waste.toString().toDouble()
                )
                viewModel.addProducts(product)

                name.clear()
                price.clear()
                tax.clear()
                waste.clear()
            }
        }
        addProductToDishBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val pickedDish     = viewModel.getDishes().value!![this!!.dishPosition!!]
            val pickedProduct  = viewModel.getProducts().value!![this!!.productPosition!!]
            viewModel.addProductToDish(pickedDish,pickedProduct,weightOfAddedProduct.text.toString().toDouble())
        }

    }

    initializeUi()
    return view
}
companion object {
    fun newInstance():Add = Add()
    const val TAG = "Add"
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post your code showing the fragment layout/fragment and view model from the 3rd fragment, with the fields?

Comment: I just added that.

Comment: in openFragment method You are replacing old framgnet with new Fragment. So when you again come to your 3rd fragment then It will create from stracth and Your previous values would be erased. This is expected Behaviour. If you do not want edittext values to erase. You have 2 options, either add framents instead of replace. But You will find hard to maintain all the states of fragments And as another option You can store the edittext values at some place and on-recreate popullate from that place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem.
So after successfully adding a product, you will return to fragment number 1 (the products list). The new product is there, great.
Now you are returning to the 3rd fragment (add product), expecting the form to still be populated (the edit text fields etc), but they are blank.

The reason for this is that on returning to the 3rd fragment the second time, `onCreateView` is called again and the entire fragment is re-created. Nowhere in this `initializeUi` method are you populating the text fields (it will not remember the values from when you were last on this fragment).

You need to populate the `EditText` fields in the `initializeUi` method from data in the view model.

```
val name = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_name).text
name.text = viewModel.someLiveDataField.value
```

Update:

Try removing `.text` from the end of these lines (and renaming them):

```
val nameEditText     = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_name)
val priceEditText    = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_price)
val taxEditText      = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_tax)
val wasteEditText    = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_waste)
```

Now, in your `OnClickListener`, change it to this:

```
val product = Product(
                    nameEditText.text,
                    priceEditText.text.toDouble(),
                    taxEditText.text.toDouble(),
                    wasteEditText.text.toDouble()
                )
```

(Apologies if syntax is slightly wrong).

Comment: The thing is that I want the EditText fields to be cleared after I add some product, and It works like supposed to, also if I have the EditText field populated and i switch back and forth they stay populated, problem is that after onCreateView is called for the second time even though EditText fields are populated app reads them as empty.

Comment: Ah I understand! I have updated my answer appropriately.